# Does the magnetic field exert a force on the magnetization current inside the ferromagnet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

Does the magnetic field exert a force on the magnetization current inside the ferromagnet?

In this case, does the following formula also apply?

$$
\pmb {d \hat F = I_{m} \ d \hat{L} \times \hat{B}} \tag{1}
$$

where $\mathbf{I}_{m}$ is the magnetization current inside the ferromagnet.

I am a little confused about the calculation of the magnetic force in the magnetostatic system.

The magnetic flux that crosses the air gap in a structure of ferromagnetic circuit produces a force of attraction between the faces of the air gap, this force is a function of the magnetic flux density as follows:

$$
\pmb {F = \frac{B_{a}^2 A_{a}}{2 \mu_{o}}} \tag{2}
$$

where $\mathbf{B}_{a}$ is magnetic flux density in webers per square meter, $\mathbf{A}_{a}$ is area of the air gap in square meters, and $\mu_{o} = 4\pi \times 10^{-7}$ H/m.

My initial thought was that the current in Equation **(1)** only represents the conduction current, not including the magnetization current, and the formula is sufficient to calculate all the forces in the magnetostatic system, no matter how complicated it is.

However, in this case, it is clear that the force acts directly between the ferromagnetic material surrounding the two faces of the gap, rather than applied to the magnetomotive force, that is, the coil carrying the conduction current that may be far from the gap.

So my question is that how can we use Equation **(1)** to calculate the force between the face of the air gap instead of using Equation **(2)** ?

If we must use Equation **(1)** to calculate the force, does it mean that the current in Equation **(1)** should represent the magnetization current inside the ferromagnetic material ?

Comment: A little more context please.

Comment: @And aka, sorry for late reply, please see the additional information I just added.

Answer (score 0):

I want to announce that now I do believe that

$$  d\hat F = \left( I_{cond} + I_{mag} \right) d \hat L \times \hat B $$

$$ d\hat F = \left(I_{mag} \right) \ d\hat L \times \hat B  \qquad \text {when} \quad 
I_{cond}=0 $$

where

***I*** cond = conduction current

***I*** mag = magnetization current

$$\\$$
Today, when I woke up from sleep, I suddenly figured out what was wrong with my reasoning.

Let me explain what happened with the help of the diagram below : -
$$\\$$
[image]

The diagram shows that the magnetization current is flowing around the side surfaces of the ferromagnetic material on the two faces of the gap.

At the beginning, I always thought that the magnetic flux distribution is like the one shown on the left. As we usually see in books or online, this magnetic flux distribution is of course correct, but I will get wrong repulsive force results.

Now, I think I should calculate the force based on the magnetic flux distribution shown on the right. Similar to calculating the force between the parallel plate capacitor, we should only consider the electric field generated by one side charge.

This means that when calculating the force of the magnetic field acting on the magnetization current on one side, only the magnetic flux generated from the other side should be considered, as shown on the right side of the diagram.

I can finally draw the correct conclusion about the attraction force between the two faces on the gap.

Although this is not an accurate mathematical analysis,  I think at least in terms of abstract reasoning,  I finally got rid of the knot in my heart.